# android launched activity exit callback function

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, android-activity

I am launching the android setting activity, from an android service.

```
Intent LaunchIntent =  getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

I am searching, how I can detect if the setting activity is closed,As I need some callback method.

If there is a callback method to know the settings or any other app like browsers,if launched in this method to know if the launched activity is exit its own.

Since settings and browsers are general code we can't put broadcast code in these activities.

Comment: You can try using the [startActivityForResult.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result)

Comment: You cannot startActivityForResult from within a service since this action is a blocking action and usually you would like a service to continue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `startActivityForResult` to launch the settings activity like so:

```
Intent LaunchIntent = 
           getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.settings");
startActivityForResult(LaunchIntent, 42);
```

Usually, you would use a specific request code as the second argument, but in this case, you have no control over what the settings Activity could return as a result, and you only want to know when it finishes, so you can essentially make up a request code. It must be greater than 0, however. The docs state this here:

> requestCode   If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.

Then, you can override the `onActivityResult` method to handle what happens when the settings activity closes:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // Do whatever you would like to do
}
```

If you had used a specific request code when you started the Activity, this is where you would check if the result code exists, but since we aren't expecting any real result, the result code will likely be equal to `RESULT_CANCELLED`, but that's okay since you at least know that the Activity was cancelled.